# PrezentDoctrineTranslatableBundle no fallback locale

Tags: php, symfony, multilingual

I use a good bundle Prezent, but he does not want to get fallback locale. All configs are registered, everything is done for [example](https://github.com/Prezent/doctrine-translatable/blob/master/doc/examples.md) in the documentation, but it does not work. Maybe someone has encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Instead of:

```
/**
 * Translation helper method
 */
public function translate($locale = null)
{
    if (null === $locale) {
        $locale = $this->currentLocale;
    }

    if (!$locale) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('No locale has been set and currentLocale is empty');
    }

    if ($this->currentTranslation && $this->currentTranslation->getLocale() === $locale) {
        return $this->currentTranslation;
    }

    if (!$translation = $this->translations->get($locale)) {
        $className = $this->getTranslationEntityClass();
        $translation = new $className;
        $translation->setLocale($locale);
        $this->addTranslation($translation);
    }

    $this->currentTranslation = $translation;
    return $translation;
}
```

Must be for use fallback locale:

```
/**
 * Translation helper method that uses a fallback locale
 */
public function translate($locale = null)
{
    if (null === $locale) {
        $locale = $this->currentLocale;
    }

    if (!$locale) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('No locale has been set and currentLocale is empty');
    }

    if ($this->currentTranslation && $this->currentTranslation->getLocale() === $locale) {
        return $this->currentTranslation;
    }

    if (!$translation = $this->translations->get($locale)) {
        if (!$translation = $this->translations->get($this->fallbackLocale)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('No translation in current or fallback locale');
        }
    }

    $this->currentTranslation = $translation;

    return $translation;
}
```

in TranslatableEntity.php from which we inherit the entity to be translated